# VB.Net Connect to a share, on different forest, and save images

Tags: vb.net, file-transfer, smb, network-share

I have one server A which lives on Domain D1, and another server B which lives on Domain D2. The two domains are not in the same forest but a connection has been setup between them so that they can talk to each other.

I need to be able to connect to a share on server B using a local account (setup on server B) and save files to the share. For Example `\\B\ShareName\images\`

Any advice on how to accomplish this? Currently attempting to use SMB2 but I am receiving errors and it is not working. Is SMB the correct protocol in this case?

Note that this process would be running as a scheduled task on Server A to transfer files from A to B daily.

The environment is using .Net  4.5. And server A should be the only one connecting to server B.

Let me know if you require more information or have any questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the environment like for the code? Does it need to be on a number of user computers? Is it a scheduled task on a specific server? Run on demand on a server as part of a web app?

Comment: Added more information to the question in the edit

Comment: You need to use a domain user that has access to the share. This question may be better asked on one of the other StackExchange websites such as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: So the issue is that the domains aren't connected. I am running into issues impersonating a user when connecting to a share